# How to read data from micro chip

Tags: microchip

I have a circuit that works in a machine. It has a microchip that has a number on it. 30281F6. I have to know How program inside the chip actually works, which steps it follow and what is the algorithm.

Unfortunately as mentioned before I have not enough information about electronic.

Please help me is it possible, If it is then how can I do that?

Thank You and Best Regards...

Comment: Please edit and ask one clear question. e.g., "Is it possible to reverse engineer the program in a 30281F6 microprocessor?" Then tell us what you know about the chip and the application.

Comment: @transistor I have edited, it is my first question and sory about that. If you help me I will appreciate...

Comment: OK, but from your question and comments I think it will be several years before you will have enough skill to do this task. If you are interested in learning then start with something like Arduino and learn to program. It is difficult enough when you have the program written in front of you with comments. It is almost impossible to understand someone else's program (by reverse engineering) without the comments. I will edit your question.

Comment: Set up something to log the inputs and outputs and run it through all the cycles.  If you suspect some things may respond in real time (water fill rate or whatever) run it through the same cycle multiple times while changing the conditions, for example partially close the valve on the water source.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no absolute certainty that your 30281F6 chip IS a micro-controller. I don't recognize the number, and it is a bit short. Including a clear picture might increase that chance that anyone recognizes it.

Next, IF it is a micro-controler, the manufacturer has almost certainly set the 'read-protection' bit, precisely because he doesn't want his product to be read out, analyzed, and maybe cloned.

There are always ways to circumvent this. For most types of micro-controlers there used to be services like 'send us 3 chips and $x and we will send you the bits in the chip', but these tend to be expensive, and probably illegal in most jurisdictions.

And no, micro-controllers tend not to be programmed in Java. In C, C++, assembler, Ada, Pacsal, or even Basic. But very rarely in Java.

Note that when you could read the chip, what you would get is just a bunch of bits. It is NOT the human-readable form of the program, that never enters the chip.

Comment: I am not going to reprogram it, just write a program works on computer. But to do that, I need information. How the program works

Comment: It could be this guy http://am.renesas.com/products/mpumcu/m16c/m16ctiny/m16c28/device/M30281F6HP. If you can't get to the flash, with the right equipment you could spend the time to observe the I/O and make assumptions to write your program (depending on what you mean in your comment).

Comment: @DigitalNinja I mean, just have to read the chip. Thats all

Comment: Your "just have to read the chip" is probably way beyond your capabilities, and what you got out of it wouldn't be very usefull.

Comment: What you're likely to get is binary output that would need to be disassembled into assembly... And while you're a computer engineer, assembly is not a fun language. As has been mentioned, given the simplicity of the program, it would be far easier to observe the output to particular settings it produces and to program your own code to mimic it. This also has the added benefit of being legal (as far as I know).